# SP2010: How to hide column based on lookup column

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm modifying a custom new/edit form, and need to hide a column based on a selection from a multiple lookup column (using resources lookup form group calendar).  I've used the following code below which works fine for a single lookup, but not for a multiple.

Rook = multiple lookup column
Title = field trying to hide

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="...../jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // add change handler
    $("select[title='Rook']").change(function() {
        MasterSelectChange();
    });
    // call the change function to set up form for first display:
    MasterSelectChange();
});

function MasterSelectChange()
{
 var mySelectValue = $("select[title='Rook']").val(); 
 if (mySelectValue == "2")
    {
     $("input[title='Title']").closest("tr").hide();

      }
    else
    {
      $("input[title='Title']").closest("tr").show();

    }
}
</script>
```

I'm also wondering, if it might be easier to have the lookup values filtered based on the dropdown value?

Comment: Try using something like SPServices i think it has functions like SPCascadedropdown or you can use something like <a href="http://alstechtips.blogspot.in/2013/08/walkthrough-conditionally-hide-fields.html">this</a>

Comment: I used to use JS on entry forms, but now I find InfoPath much more effective for making these types of customizations - might be worth checking into if you haven't before.

Comment: I wish I could use InfoPath but the place I work at does not have InfoPath 2010..we're still on Office 2007.